# In C#, how do I bind an array to DataGridView such that the values in the array are displayed?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual C# 2010 Express.  I have an Array of strings like this arr[100][2]. Here's my 3 lines of code

```
 string FilePath = @"c:\data.txt";
 var arrData = File.ReadLines(FilePath).Select(line => line.Split('\t')).ToArray();
 dataGridView1.DataSource = arrData;
```

When I run the code I see 7 column headers in the DataGridView control instead of the contents of my array: Length, LongLength, Rank, SyncRoot, IsReadOnly, IsFixedSize, and IsSynchronized.  What is this?

Somehow, I am displaying the attributes of the array instead of the values actually contained inside of the array.

I know there are legit values in the array because when I step through the code I can clearly see the contents (names and ages).  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you say what is your application? Is it asp.net, wpf or something else?

Comment: It's a WindowsFormsApplication.  And these are the only lines of code (attached to a button click event).

Comment: Also, please consider using a CSV / TSV library rather than writing your own code.  I put my tiny minimalist unit-tested library here: https://code.google.com/p/csharp-csv-reader/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try converting to a list of "objects" first.  I created a test file with a first name, last name and an age all separated by a tab to test:

```
string FilePath = @"c:\data.txt";
var arrData = File.ReadLines(FilePath).Select(line => 
                                              line.Split('\t')).ToArray();

var query = from x in arrData
            select new { FirstName = x[0], LastName = x[1], Age = x[2] };

dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

I would think what you are attempting would be fairly error prone.  I would consider first converting the file to an actual list of objects first.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just make your arrData a List instead. So it would be this instead:

```
 string FilePath = @"c:\data.txt";
 var arrData = File.ReadLines(FilePath).Select(line => line.Split('\t')).ToList();
 dataGridView1.DataSource = arrData;
```

This should be all you need to do. Also, be sure to make sure that your arrData actually has data in it too :)

Comment: Same result as ToArray() actually.

Comment: @Chris.  Hi.  Changing it to a list with ToList() had absolutely no effect.  Same results.  It doesn't display what's inside my List, but instead showed what I mentioned above.  And yes, I can see that arrData has data in it. :)